# Pagination does not work correctly when table data is changed from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables, jquery-pagination

I am using following code to update the datatable from Django View

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'filter/',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      data:{"no_days":no_days},
      success: function(res){
        var tableData="";
        $.each(res, function(key, value){
                tableData += '<tr>';
                tableData += '<td>' + value.from_project + '</td>';
                tableData += '<td>' + value.billing_id + '</td>';
                tableData += '<td>' + value.total + '</td>';
                tableData += '</tr>';
        });

        $('#tableBounceBody').html(tableData);
        $('#eBounceTable').DataTable();

        // $('#eBounceTable').DataTable({}).ajax.reload();
        // $('#eBounceTable').Datatable().draw();
        
      },
      error:function(res){console.log("Something went wrong!")}
    });
```

The first page is displayed correctly when this code updates the data, but as soon as I use the pagination to move to the next page, it reverts back to previous data and deletes the update.

So my question is, how to update datatable in jQuery datatable after ajax success ? I am assuming that I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: If you really want to handle your DataTable in this way, you can `$('#eBounceTable').DataTable().destroy();` before you `$('#tableBouceBody').html(tableData);`. But in my experience, that is typically unnecessary and needlessly expensive. You should be able to use DataTables' [built-in support for Ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) instead, as one way to avoid this.

Comment: Extra notes: (1) is `tableBouceBody` correct? looks like a typo. (2) there are lots of similar questions here on SO with similar - and alternative - solutions. So, you may get more ideas by doing some additional research. If nothing meets your needs, then maybe a [mre] will help us.